# Regular expression: Match a string starting with some symbol, continue with left match

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a long string, for example:

> sometext~ZA÷sometext1~textsome1~text~ZA÷sometext2~textsome3~text~.......

I want a array string:

- item1: ZA÷sometext1~textsome1~text~
- item2: ZA÷sometext2~textsome2~text~
- item3: ZA÷sometext3~textsome3~text~
- ...

I tried pattern: ZA÷(.*?)~

It's only match ZA÷sometext~, and I've missing result.
Anyone help me resolve my problem. I don't know much about regex!

EDIT:
That string is just an example. It may be:

> ZA÷ACDK¬ZEE÷EcZwBi3N¬ZB÷1¬ZY÷Africa¬ZC÷nyyrdizT¬ZD÷p¬ZE÷QDSL‌​ZVAl¬ZF÷0¬ZO÷0¬ZG÷1¬‌​ZH÷1_EcZwBi3N¬ZJ÷2¬Z‌​L÷/legue¬ZX÷00Africa‌​......006Africa00100‌​00000002000CAF
>   Champion020League000¬~AA÷j3xCaVI8¬AD÷1471966200¬AB÷1¬CR÷1¬AC‌​÷1¬CX÷Enyimba¬AX÷0¬B‌​X÷-1¬WM÷ENY¬AE÷Enyim‌​ba¬WU÷enyimba-intern‌​ational¬WN÷MAM¬AF÷Ma‌​melodi Sundowns¬WV÷mamelodi-sundowns¬AN÷y¬MW÷16|4.........

It's a complex string, which rules

Answer (score 1):

Just change you pattern to:

```
"ZA÷(.*?)~(.*?)~(.*?)~"
```

Comment: That string is just an example. It may be: ZA÷ACDK¬ZEE÷EcZwBi3N¬ZB÷1¬ZY÷Africa¬ZC÷nyyrdizT¬ZD÷p¬ZE÷QDSLZVAl¬ZF÷0¬ZO÷0¬ZG÷1¬ZH÷1_EcZwBi3N¬ZJ÷2¬ZL÷/legue¬ZX÷00Africa......006Africa0010000000002000CAF Champion020League000¬~AA÷j3xCaVI8¬AD÷1471966200¬AB÷1¬CR÷1¬AC÷1¬CX÷Enyimba¬AX÷0¬BX÷-1¬WM÷ENY¬AE÷Enyimba¬WU÷enyimba-international¬WN÷MAM¬AF÷Mamelodi Sundowns¬WV÷mamelodi-sundowns¬AN÷y¬MW÷16|4....

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following pattern

```
(ZA÷.*?)ZA÷
```

The edit string is a sample but it doesn't have repeated `ZA÷` thus cannot test it properly. But I m sure this gonna work for you, if it matches the pattern shown above.

**EDIT**

After getting the full string this seems to be working

```
.+?(?=ZA÷)
```

`.+?` matches any character (except newline)

Quantifier:

`+?` Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]

`(?=ZA÷)` Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched

Comment: It's still missing result. I've uploaded my string into my gg drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1KkAKXAmtVQUkdPWDJfZUZRSGM. 
Can you give a new pattern. Thank you very much

Comment: Have a look at the edited part of the answer. This will give 61 strings probably u wanted.

Comment: It's still missing result. The first match: SA÷1¬~ is failure. And the last match: ZA÷WORLD: Club... is missing. :(

Comment: According to me it matched the first one. But yes the last one is missing. :) I'll get back to SO after 1:30 hour.

Comment: My friend give this pattern: (ZA÷((?!ZA÷).)*), it's work well :)

Answer (score 0):

My friend give this pattern: (ZA÷((?!ZA÷).)*), it's work well. Thank you all for your help! :D